# Clearing Cookies and localStorage not fully working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

My Django web app used to give me

```
400 Bad Request. Request Header or Cookie Too Large
```

error every now and then. I used to solve this by manually clearing Cookies from inspect element menu (in Chrome). So I figured that as long I can have some code that clears cookies regularly, I shouldnt run into this isue again (true till now).

I have the following event :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#logout" , "#login").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cookies = Cookies.get();
            for(var cookie in cookies) {
                Cookies.remove(cookie);
            }
            window.localStorage.clear();
            window.location.href="{% url 'logout' %}";
        });
    });
```

Which should clear cookies and local storage items. The issue is that only a portion of the items are cleared which means that, over time, cookies and localStorage elements can accumulate and might cause issues.

"http only" Cookies arent accessible using Javascript, but the "http" column in inspect element > Application > Cookies menu is empty (which I assume means they arent http only cookies).

So my questions are:

1) Why might some Cookies not be deleted by the above code?

2) Why might some localStorage items not be deleted by the above code?

3) Is there another way to solve the 400 Bad Request issue without doing all of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this issue is caused by too large cookies? Did you try finding out what cookie was too large (I think the network panel in Chrome should help you here)?

Comment: @Jb31 if clearing cookies solves the problem then what else could be the issue?

Comment: @Jb31 Also, replicating this error is quite difficult as Cookies need to be accumulated over time for it to happen (or so I believe).

Comment: 1. `httponly` cookies cannot be access by Javascript hence wont get deleted.
2. localStorage will get cleaned if `localStorage.clear()` is called
3. This happens when cookie data exceeds 4kb. Check if the app stores session info in cookie.

Comment: @CerlinBoss 1. So there is absolutly no way to delete them? 2.Look at the above code 3.yes it does, I am saving the html code of two website in session for display. But they should be cleared on logout.